# Django | How to make a reverse Relationship with two models

Tags: django, class, model, relationship, prefetch

i want to make a ticket system. I have the main model (TicketSystem) and a model with the messages from the users (TicketSystem_Messages).

In the model "TicketSystem_Messages" is the ForeignKey to the model "TicketSystem".

Here is my code:

```
class TicketSystem(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(_('Subject'),max_length=30, blank=False, default="N/A")
    message = models.TextField(_('Message'), null=False, blank=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Date'), default=datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc))
    fertig_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Date'), default=datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc))

class TicketSystem_Messages(models.Model):
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User)
    status = models.ForeignKey(TicketSystem_Status)
    ticketid = models.ForeignKey(TicketSystem)
    message = models.TextField(_('Message'), null=False, blank=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Sent'), default=datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc))
```

At the moment i get the Tickets without the Messages:

```
sql_TicketSystem = TicketSystem.objects.filter(id=kwargs['pk'])
```

I want to make a LEFT JOIN like this

```
SELECT * FROM TicketSystem LEFT JOIN TicketSystem_Messages ON Ticketsystem.id = TicketSystem_Messages.ticketid
```

I heard something about "select_related" and "prefetch_related" and tried it but it does not work.

Comment: I am not an expert in SQL so join doesn't makes much sense to me. Your got the ticket `sql_TicketSystem = TicketSystem.objects.filter(id=kwargs['pk'])` are you trying to get all the `TicketSystem_Messages` related to that ticket id?

Comment: The problem is that a ticket does not always have messages, therefore no ticket would be found if there is no message for the ticket

Comment: After you get a ticket `TicketSystem.objects.filter(id=kwargs['pk'])` You can query for all messages related to it. It will return all related messages in a queryset or an empty queryset. use `sql_TicketSystem.ticketsystem_messages_set.all()`

Comment: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'TicketSystem_Messages_set'

Comment: it's `ticketsystem_messages_set` not `TicketSystem_Messages_set`

Comment: yeah thanks @dirkgroten, its `ticketsystem_messages_set` my bad, I copy pasted the class name in hurry..

Comment: `prefetch_related` should work. If you do `sql_TicketSystem = TicketSystem.objects.filter(id=kwargs['pk']).prefetch_related('ticketsystem_messages_set')` then `sql_TicketSystem[0].ticketsystem_messages_set.all()` gives you the queryset of all related messages without querying again the db. Note the `[0]` (I'm getting the first object in the Queryset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using raw SQL joins, in Django you can traverse model relationships in either direction, regardless of how they are represented in the database.

To find all the messages for a given `TicketSystem` instance:

```
my_ticket = TicketSystem.objects.get(id=0) # or something
my_ticket_messages = my_ticket.ticketsystem_messages_set.all() # or do other filters here
```

To find all the messages using a `queryset`:

```
TicketSystem_Messages.objects.filter(ticketId=my_ticket)
```

To find all tickets with more than one message:

```
from django.db import Count
TicketSystem.objects.annotate(message_count=Count('ticketsystem_messagess')).filter(message_count__gt=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i want to list all tickets with the last status from the model "TicketSystem_Messages", it doesnt work. So with "TicketSystem.objects.get" it works without any problems.

Example:

```
sql_TicketSystem = TicketSystem.objects.all()
sql_TicketSystem_Messages = sql_TicketSystem.ticketsystem_messages_set.all()
```

**UPDATE:**

```
{% for data in sql_TicketSystem %}
     {{ data.subject }}
     {% for msg in data.ticketsystem_messages_set.all %}
          {{msg.status}}
     {% empty %}
          Unknown
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works :-)